# POI HSSF class missing for Tika-app-1.10

Tags: apache-poi, apache-tika, hssf

For legacy reasons I was using `org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.UnaryPlusPtg`class in my project. but due to Tika parser's dependency resolution issues, I had to delete old POI jar files from the project. Now the build fails because of `org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.UnaryPlusPtg` package is missing. Then I found out that this class also exists in `org.apache.poi.ss.formula.ptg.UnaryPlusPtg`. Does it mean that the package has been migrated or be exchanged with wherever I used the hssf-package entries?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to use the UnaryPlusPtg class directly in the first place? Why does your code need to use this class in the first place?

Comment: Very simple explanation - "That is not my code" - I am trying to tell people off and wanted a reason for this. Seems like you have given me one!

Comment: The Ptg classes are pretty low level, you almost never need to touch them in normal uses of Apache POI. Are you sure those are really needed, and not (say) an un-used or incorrect import?

Comment: As I said, I was doing some code/project review and realised that those use cases are rare but didn't to drop old poi jars without identifying these issues. The problem is solved. As you guys mentioned, those are used for very low level code (not by consumer-side developers I believe).